# Entity Framework Validation Error On Entity Not Being Modified

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

Here's my controller action:

```
public JsonResult Add(Mod.Payment payment)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Ent.Payment paymentEnt = new Ent.Payment();
        Mapper.Map(payment, paymentEnt);
        db.Payments.Add(paymentEnt);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Payment(paymentEnt.PaymentId);
    } else
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return Json(new { Message = "Not OK" });
    }

}
```

db.SaveChanges triggers EntityValidationErrors.  The errors are not for the "paymentEnt" entity, but for related entities that are included with the payment View Model and Entity via navigation properties.

I'm not modifying those entities, only "paymentEnt".  So how can I get Entity Framework to not try to validate them or to ignore their errors?

I could create another Payment ViewModel that excludes related entities, but that would violate DRY.

Comment: @ashin's response worked, so I'm considering this closed.  I would have included more of my code, but there's a lot of it and I wanted to be as succinct as possible.  But thanks for engaging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could explicitly mark the related entities as Unchanged/Detached, if you want EF to skip them:

```
db.Entry(paymentEnt.RelatedEntity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;
```